# rails-settings-cached gem with rake task in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, rubygems

I have been using [rails-settings-cached](https://github.com/huacnlee/rails-settings-cached) for sometime (I believed successfully). My setup and usage is broadly as described in the readme for the gem (with an admin interface as described).

I have an integer setting named :max_apples set to 2 and that setting is referenced in my controller as

```
@max_apples = Setting.max_apples
```

and onto my view as

```
<%= @max_apples %>
```

When the view is rendered, it correctly shows 2 and if, for example I change this setting from 2 to 3 in the admin interface, when that view is next rendered, it correctly shows 3. This works as expected locally and in production.

However I have noticed that when such a setting is referenced in a rake task (in production only) the update does not appear to be recognised.

For example:

```
desc 'write a setting to output'
task output_setting: :environment do
  puts Setting.max_apples
end
```

**In Development (all as expected)**

[:max_apples set to 2]

```
$ rake output_setting # 2
```

[ change :max_apples to 3 through admin interface]

```
$ rake output_setting # 3
```

And
[:max_apples set to 2]

```
$ rails c

Setting.max_apples # 2

Setting.find(1) 
#<Setting:0x00007f9dd66fc068 id: 1, var: "max_apples", value: "--- 2\n">
```

[ change :max_apples to 3 through admin interface]

```
Setting.max_apples # 3 
$ Setting.find(1)
#<Setting:0x00007f9dd66fc068 id: 1, var: "max_apples", value: "--- 3\n">
```

**Production (not as expected)**

[:max_apples set to 2]

```
$ rake output_setting # 2 [as expected]
```

[ change :max_apples to 3 through admin interface]

```
$ rake output_setting # 2 [Expect 3]
```

And
[:max_apples set to 2]

```
$ heroku run rails c --sandbox
Setting.max_apples # 2
$ Setting.find(1)
#<Setting:0x00007f9dd66fc068 id: 1, var: "max_apples", value: "--- 2\n">
```

[ change :max_apples to 3 through admin interface]

```
Setting.max_apples # 2 [Expect 3]
$ Setting.find(1)
#<Setting:0x00007f9dd66fc068 id: 1, var: "max_apples", value: "--- 3\n"> # [database updated correctly]
```

Could I have some help please understanding why this is happening and what change to make so I can run settings dependent rake tasks correctly.

Thank you

Daniel